# Spent hours trying to troubleshoot Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined, app previously worked now it doesn't

Tags: reactjs

I've reduced this app to as basic as I possible could and still get the error. The only last thing to do is put jsx inside the index page directly, obviously that is not what I want to do.

I am using webpack and babel if that is worth anything.

The index.js page is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.js';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
root.render(<App />);
```

App.js:

```
export default function App() {


    return (
                
        <h1>TEST</h1>


    );
}
```

The error messages I am getting are:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    App webpack://myproject/./assets/App.js?:6
    React 11
    workLoop webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:266
    flushWork webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:533
    EventHandlerNonNull* webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:571
    <anonymous> webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:633
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:89
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/index.js?:4
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:99
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    React 2
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:39
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> React
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:59
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> React
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:49
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> webpack://myproject/./assets/index.js?:4
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:29
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:187
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:189
index-bundle.js line 19 > eval:6:3


The above error occurred in the <App> component:

App@webpack://myproject/./assets/App.js?:6:3

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. react-dom.development.js:18687:15
    React 12
    workLoop webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:266
    flushWork webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:533
    (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
    <anonymous> webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:571
    <anonymous> webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js?:633
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:89
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> webpack://myproject/./node_modules/scheduler/index.js?:4
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:99
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    React 2
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:39
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> React
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:59
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> React
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:49
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> webpack://myproject/./assets/index.js?:4
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:29
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:123
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:187
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index-bundle.js:189
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.15.0"
  }
}
```

my `webpack.congif.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './assets/index.js',  // path to our input file
  output: {
    filename: 'index-bundle.js',  // output bundle file name
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),  // path to our Django static directory
  },
  
  /*Use Babel's env and react presets to compile all 
  .js and .jsx files that aren't inside the node_modules directory*/
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] }
      },
    ]
  }
```

};

Comment: Try importing react into App.js. `<h1>` is JSX for `React.createElement(‘h1’)` so React needs to be in the file as a variable. It’s not a global variable.

Comment: @AndyRay From React 18, that't not required. https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#whats-different-in-the-new-transform

Comment: Since you are using `webpack`, do you have an `externals` key and is `react` present in it? If yes, remove it from `externals`.

Comment: @AndyRay, tried that previously, didn't solve it.

Comment: @RobinThomas, nope, no externals key. My webpack is as basic as it gets.

Comment: Do you have a public github repo I can take a look at?

Comment: I edited the question to include my package.json and webpack config. I'm trying to integrate it into an existing django project.  I erased my 'test' app above and copied pasted the react instillation docs example, still didn't work.

Comment: @ttat2g possible to share a minimum reproducible github repo? Will be easier for me to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if posting an answer you don't understand goes against the SO guidelines but I `Git reset` to reset the HEAD to before I installed React and the JS tooling, just in case, then reinstalled `React`, `Babel`, `Webpack` along with some webpack plugins, for testing all I used was `HtmlWebpack`

Then instead of rendering from the server running Django, I used `webpack-dev-server`. Once I confirmed that my `Index.js` file could actually receive the `App` component, I removed that and changed `webpack`'s output to the `index-bundle.js` file which is rendered in a django template. It worked.
The only console error to fix is to move over from ReactDOM in line with React 18.

Again, I don't know why reinstalling everything suddenly fixed it.

Here's the updated `webpack.config.js` file:

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./assets/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: 'index-bundle.js',
    path:path.resolve(__dirname, "./static"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
          } 
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
}
```